# What happen when user login?

Tags: active-directory

My teacher ask me question that I didn't find on the book.

The question is:

How it could be after I connect once to my User I can connect without network,

I mean: when the network Plug-in to my computer and I connect to the network/intranet, I login/authentication once, and after that I can plug-out the intranet cable and still login.

my questions are:

1. What happen when someone authentication in the first time?
2. How I can cancel that "Cache", How to require someone must to be connect to intranet to login